# JSON call breaks on mirrored domain

Tags: javascript, php, json, iframe, svg

I have a site that displays several SVG maps and when a user clicks on hotspots an iframe populates with data pulled from various JSON files depending on the map displayed.

Recently, we've been given a directive to create a new domain name, and transition away from the old domain (yep, a gov't project). Below is the iframe template code for the map that is broken, and simply displays **"The requested content cannot be loaded.
Please try again later."**

It is only broken when accessed from the new domain, which is defined as domain alias currently, so this shouldn't be related to cross-domain calling or CORS, right? Again, only 1 out of 6 SVG maps is having this issue.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: COUNTY: Iframe Fancybox
*/

if(!$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FANCYBOX']) {

$url = str_replace('info','geo',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);     _err("iframe: $url");
header("Location: $url");
}

$i       = $_GET['i'];
$bubbles = json_decode(file_get_contents('wp-content/plugins/svg_map/data/2016/all-bubbles.json'),true);
$region  = $bubbles['chart_data'][0]['counties'][$i];

?>
```

My initial thought was to hardcode the new domain into the **file_get_contents** parameter, but that didn't work. To be sure, I hardcoded both versions of the domain. I feel like I'm missing something obvious. I tried searching here and on google, but had a difficult time articulating the question, so I wasn't getting any good results. Any suggestions would be appreciated, and I apologize if the question is lacking the actual website links to look at.

Comment: There's no JavaScript code there. CORS has nothing to do with server-side code; it only applies when cross-domain HTTP requests are being made from JavaScript in a browser.

Comment: "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later" is a very vague error message. There is probably a better one somewhere.  Is there a (probably very subtle) Advanced or Details link near the error message? What does the Console in the browser say? What does the Network tab say?

Comment: you'd need to show the code that's generating this "cannot be displayed" message. the above php code is essentially useless, since you haven't shown/explained HOW it's related to the error-generating code

Comment: Thanks Pointy, Quentin, and Marc B,
I've solved the issue. You all offered good insight, which was really what I needed. I immediately focused on the Console output, and quickly discovered the issue with the URL being passed, and how WordPress was guessing incorrectly on the aliased domain. A quick **Replace All** with the appropriate values to the relative links in the SVG fixed the issue, and it's working on both sites.

PS: StackOverflow and it's users rock! Thank you all